# Strange keyboard events on Win8 HP laptop

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have had a HP Pavillion forever, running Win8. Lately, it has been acting weirdly, and I assumed it was simply on its deathbed. But the weirdness is getting even weirder now. Other than it sometimes acting like the button 5 (I think on the NumPad) is being held down until I press NumLock, the keyboard switches off except for the function keys when my kitten jumps up on it. I thought that was it, so I bought a USB keyboard and noticed that the CapsLock on the actual keyboard reacted, both when I used the USB keyboard and the onscreen keyboard available via the control panel. And just moments ago, my kitten stood on the keyboard, and now it works again!
I am no longer entirely sure that it is a malfunction. There are many unmarked key effects, like flight mode and silence, that go on or off when the cat steps on completely unrelated keys, and this on/off keyboard thing seems to suggest that there is an unmarked key or combination that allows the main keyboard to be turned on and off again. I'd love that function in general, but right now, I just want to be able to turn it back on next time the cat decides to flick the switch to off!
(I had a minor, early version of this problem posted, with no real answer found: [Strange button effect on Windows 8 laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/1670650/strange-button-effect-on-windows-8-laptop?noredirect=1#comment2561784_1670650))

Comment: More likely the keyboard needs cleaning, as some key is a bit sticky, but more cat-presses release it.

Comment: No, it shuts off ALL keys except funktion keys, so it is not because of dirt

Comment: Holding shift for 8 seconds might lock some keyboards: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Keyboard-is-locked-What-keys-do-I-press-to-unlock-it/td-p/6321820

Comment: Otherwise your cat may be "helpfully" enabling Filterkeys: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/To-unlock-the-key-of-keyboard-of-HP-Pavilion-g-series-laptop/td-p/6330529

Comment: I thought so, too, but it does not react to toggling Filterkeys, and holding shift for 8 seconds again does nothing. I think it might be a virus or something....